# Can I use HTTP COPY Request with axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, copy, httprequest

To interact with a CouchDB instance I need to send a HTTP "COPY" request. (Non standard http request).

If I use Postman to send the request it works fine. But within my webapp I use axios, and with axios sending a COPY request results in errors. (Strangely, CORS errors).

I use axios this way:

```
axios(
   { method:'copy',
    url: '....',
    ...
   }
)
```

I can't find much about HTTP "COPY" requests and I wonder if axios or maybe even a browser might not be able to send a COPY request?

Any tipp would be great! Thank you.

Console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5984/somedoc/505282119b93327fa4fecbef68026db4_cp' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

OK, for now i understand there is a preflight Request and the Browser says that the preflight failed in some way.

I see "Method Not Allowed", but COPY is listet under "Allowed".

What i do not understand is what's wrong with my request in axios while it works fine in Postman.

(Btw. all other Requests: get, put, delete.. work in axios)

Thats what i see in Chrome:

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost:5984/somedoc/505282119b93327fa4fecbef68026db4_cp
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5984
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-type, cache-control, accept-ranges, etag, server, x-couch-request-id, x-couch-update-newrev, x-couchdb-body-time
Allow: DELETE,GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,COPY
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 12:36:30 GMT
Server: CouchDB/2.3.1 (Erlang OTP/19)
X-Couch-Request-ID: 61447fcae4
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0

Request Headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,la;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type,destination
Access-Control-Request-Method: COPY
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5984
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: You say you get errors - what errors? Please [edit] your question to show some actual code you've run, and the exact errors it produces.

Comment: `Strangely CORS errors` - not so strange if it's a cross origin request ...

Comment: a browser can send anything as the method - if the method isn't allowed, then the server would respond with a 405 error

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it now:

Its a problem with couchDB as an HTTP Server. Couch does not know OPTION Requests, so CORS preflight fails.

Same COPY request works in Postman because Postman does not care about CORS and does not do a prefligt request.

Solution seems to have a proxy in front of couchdb...